# MIN, DATEADD, DATEPART, DATEDIFF functions cause table scan

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014

A performance issue has been brought to my attention.

It appears an application executes a query from time to time that takes nearly 3 minutes to execute successfully.

The column is of data type 'datetime, not null'

The column is the clustered index of the table.

The query does not use this index however, it uses a non-clustered index of another column that just happens to include this `datetime` column.  The other column is not referenced in this query.

Example query:

```
SELECT MIN(DATEADD(second, DATEPART(second, [tablename].[DateAndTime]), 
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [tablename].[DateAndTime]), 0))) AS 
    [Mindate],   
    MAX(DATEADD(second, DATEPART(second, [tablename].[DateAndTime]), 
    DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [tablename].[DateAndTime]), 0))) 
    AS [Maxdate] 
FROM [dbo].[tablename] [tablename] 
GROUP BY ();
```

the resulting output looks like this.

```
Min Date                  Max Date
2015-04-01 00:00:00.000   2015-10-05 11:56:27.000
```

The only thing I can think its doing this is because the query has to peer inside each row and pick apart the date into sections, it has no choice but to go through every row to do this.

I am hoping there is some way the query could be re-written so that it would simply just use the index to bring back the `min` and `max` values in the `DateAndTime` column and maybe format the output last?

Comment: What is `GROUP BY ()` for?

Comment: Also, are you just trying to trim milliseconds from the output?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what the GROUP BY () Is used for in this instance.  maybe for the purposes of this question it can be ignored?  this is an application generated query that I captured with profiler trace so I don't know why its doing what its doing I was just hoping I could figure out a way to generate the same type of output and provide it to the application developer to review.  thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach instead (assuming the point of all the dateadd/datediff operations are just to set the millisecond component to 0). The query was adapted to the AdventureWorks database:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(19), MIN(OrderDate), 121)), 
  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(19), MAX(OrderDate), 121))
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader GROUP BY ();
```

The trick is to find the rows **before** you start messing with the column values applying all kinds of formatting and date manipulation. This results in a much more efficient plan as long as there is a supporting index on the `OrderDate` column (and no worse than your current query if there is no supporting index):

> [image]

Yes, they are still scans, and there are two instead of one. But the impact on actual execution is undeniable:

> [image]

Comment: Yes this is a great improvement thank you so much!